# Derivatives at the zero point of a conformal map from the unit strip onto the unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis, quasiconformal-maps

Let $w$ be a point in the unit strip $\mathbb{S}=\{z\in \mathbb{C} : 0< Re\, z<1\}$ and let $\phi_w$ be a conformal map  from $\mathbb{S}$ onto the unit disc $\mathbb{D}$ with $\phi_w(w)=0$. 
It is well-known that $\phi_w$ is unique up to multiplication by a fixed number of modulus $1$, and that $\phi'_w(w)\neq 0$.

Question: Is  $\phi^{(k)}_w(w)\neq 0$ for every  $k\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: why would you suspect that? any particular reason?

Comment: I wanted to show that, given $g\in H_\infty(\mathbb{S})$ --a bounded holomorphic funcion on $\mathbb{S}$-- with a zero of order $n$ in $w$, we can write $g=\phi_w^n\cdot f$ with $f\in H_\infty(\mathbb{S})$.

Comment: doing some rough computations for $w=\frac{1}{2}$, I think that already $\phi''(w)=0$ as the result of $\phi^{(k)}(w)$ seems to be a multiple of $\zeta(-k)$ - note that $\phi(w)=\frac{e^{i\pi(w-\frac{1}{2})}-1}{e^{i\pi(w-\frac{1}{2})}+1}$

Comment: the original problem about $H^{\infty}(\mathbb S)$ is interesting and I will think on it